# When adding to an array with a for loop, it is replacing everything in the array before it

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, joptionpane

So I am doing a simple project for my cs II class and we need to use JOptionPane to get all of out information, instead of scanners. I do not know if this is causing this issue for me or if it is because we have to use 4 classes, a main, a GUI class, a controller class and a model class.

This is the code in my model class, I am trying to get to make an array of all the locations that the user enters through JOPtionPane in the GUI class. So it goes through the controller and into the model class.

So in the code it is asking for a location, and then I want to add it to the array. I understand fully why this code is replacing every element of the array with the last location entered, because it is running the full for loop everytime that it gets one location. I just do not know how to solve this problem! any help would be apprectiated. Thanks

```
public void addLocation(String location) {
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        locations[i] = location;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "_it_ is running the full for loop everytime that it gets one location"? You're the code writer, and you wrote a for loop that replaces every element in the array.  If you don't want to replace every element in the array, don't write a for loop that replaces every element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc it does, locations[i] does not return the character at place i, it returns the string, which gets interpreted to true because it's set, which is interpreted as 1, so your function just sets locations[1] = "location".

You need to turn your string into an array of chars first using something like this:

```
String str = "lcoation"; 
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

And then looping over that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of this:

```
//iterator attribute to keep track of current index
private int iterator = 0;

public void addLocation(String location) {
    //insert our location at the index indicated by our iterator
    locations[iterator] = location;

    //increment our iterator so we use the next position on the next function call
    iterator++;
}
```

Comment: Without proper index checking, such a code would tear itself apart with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when **iterator++** exceeds or equals **locations.length**

Comment: True, in the final program you'd wanna have proper index checks ofc. Altho I would also prefer to use a List instead of an array in the first place.

Comment: Some people here have a certain idea of Copy-Pasting the solution, so disasters happen when the Copy-Pasted code is run on their side. So we make sure that our solution is not the one responsible for the disasters that happen after the Copy-Pasted code is executed :) , and you are damn right about the use of java.util.List

Comment: thank you this is helpful. I think what i will do is add an if statement before iterator++ and say if(iterator<locations.length) { iterator++}

Answer (score 0):

**So in the code it is asking for a location, and then I want to add it to the array. I understand fully why this code is replacing every element of the array with the last location entered**, Primarily you are restricting yourself to the use of Arrays, in such a case, you might try something like

```
private int arrayIndexCounter = 0; // make sure this is global variable

public void addLocation(String location)
{
   locations[arrayIndexCounter] = location;
   arrayIndexCounter = (arrayIndexCounter + 1) % locations.length;
}
```

The statement **arrayIndexCounter = (arrayIndexCounter + 1) % locations.length** makes sure that you never really exceed the bounds of your array and stay within the limits of your array size(From Start to End with locations.length exclusive because if arrayIndexCounter == locations.length, your arrayIndexCounter sets itself back to zero since n % n == 0). Hope that helps??

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `List<String>` instead of an array, so that you can add and remove elements at will, and call `locations.toArray(new String[locations.size()])` whenever an array is needed.